# Move files in folders dependent on the file date

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, cmd, directory

I'm trying to sort some thousand files on a Windows server into multiple folders. File names are Extract_YYYYMMDDHHMISS.dat where YYYY is the year, MM is the month and DD is the date. I want to move these files to a folder hierarchy that I have defined as follows:

```
Archive\2013\01\01
Archive\2013\01\02
Archive\2013\01\03
...
Archive\2013\02\01
```

and so on.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%f in ('dir Extract_* /b') do (
echo %%f
echo %%~15,8f
)
endlocal
```

I'm trying to use a for loop and string formatting to get the YYYYMMDD part into a variable, and then further split it, but I'm stuck for now.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this and remove the `echo` if the output is OK:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for %%i in (Extract_*.dat) do (
    set "fname=%%~i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "name=!fname:*_=!"
    set "year=!name:~0,4!"
    set "month=!name:~4,2!"
    set "day=!name:~6,2!"
    echo move "!fname!" "Archive\!year!\!month!\!day!"
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Its not working for me. Some testing suggests its not going in the for loop. maybe a /f flag?
Secondly, "Extract" might contain multiple _ characters. So full name is like Extract_Full_Data_Over_Time_20130101121314.dat. I see you're using the _ check. Can I do a last underscore check?

Comment: @Endoro: That sounded as good as an aphorism to me. :) Anyway, you could easily fix your script. You could extract the name only (`%%~ni`), then work on the last 8 chars (`!fname:~-8!`). And the `"%%~i"` could still be used as the original name (the `move` command's first argument), so no variable would be required apart from those you've already got.

Comment: @AndriyM you are right :) and the work is mostly done. the second answer from captcha can easily be here included by the OP.

Comment: @Endoro can you explain the difference between !fname! and %fname%?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "YYYY"=="20NN" pattern to extract the core file name:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set name=Extract_Full_Data_Over_Time_20130101121314.dat
set core=%name:*_2=2%
echo %core%
20130101121314.dat
```

Obviously you shouldn't do this with file dates before 2000.

Comment: Great. This works basically. I'm trying to use a for loop to access all files as follows. Is the syntax different for a loop?
`for /f %%f in ('Extract_Full_Data_Over_Time_* /b') do (
echo %%f
echo %f:*_2=2%
)`